# Why is page that's not loaded first taking so long to reload?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having a very difficult time improving the page load time of a page that requires many database calls. It takes about 5 seconds to load.

Here's my situation. I have two separate single page tempates, FastPage.pl and SlowPage.pl. FastPage.pl downloads quickly, SlowPage.pl is the slow loading page with many calls. I have the following navbars for FastPage.pl and SlowPage.pl:

```
<!--Page A Navbar-->
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="FastPage.pl" data-prefetch="true" class="ui-state-persist">Fast Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="SlowPage.pl" data-prefetch="true">Slow Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Page B Navbar-->
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="FastPage.pl" data-prefetch="true">Fast Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="SlowPage.pl" class="ui-state-persist" data-prefetch="true">Slow Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So here's the problem I'm having:

**Scenario 1: Load FastPage.pl first**

1. Load FastPage.pl first, it loads instantly.
2. Click on SlowPage.pl link, it loads instantly (apparently because of prefetch).
3. Click back to FastPage.pl. It loads instantly.
4. Click back to SlowPage.pl. This page now loads very slowly.

Clicking back and forth between links, SlowPage.pl now always loads slowly even though it loaded quickly in step 2. Why doesn't it still load quickly like in step 2?

**Scenario 2: Load SlowPage.pl first**

1. Load SlowPage.pl first, it loads slowly, as expected.
2. Click on FastPage.pl link, it loads instantly.
3. Click back to SlowPage.pl. It loads instantly.
4. Toggling between pages is very quick.

What explains this difference in behavior in these scenarios? More importantly, is there anything I can do to get the SlowPage.pl page to reload quickly all the time once it has been loaded?

Comment: One other observation I would like to mention. The loading spinner often does not load when clicking back to the SlowPage.pl. Or, if it does show up, it doesn't actually spin, it just sits there doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just (re)discovered this bit of documentation:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/#DOMCache

This explains the behavior I see perfectly. I fixed the problem simply by adding:

`data-dom-cache="true"` key/value pair to the `<div role="page">` div.